# mod_tile make has error while building from source

Tags: apache2, opensuse

I want to install mod_tile on opensuse. I am following the [link](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/HowTo_mod_tile) to install it; after

```
#./configure
```

I run make:

```
#make
```

it shows the below error:

```
make[1]: *** [src/gen_tile.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/mod_tiles_src/mod_tile'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its duplicate of the [Other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797019/not-able-to-build-mod-tile-on-opensuse)

i used the code from

https://github.com/springmeyer/mod_tile

which is working fine..